# Jasper Reports, Expanding a Band Based on the Data in a Chart

Tags: jasper-reports, gantt-chart

Is there a way to get a band to resize based on the amount of data presented in a gantt chart? I can get the number of rows that are in the chart, if that helps. It seems like there should be a way around this.

In otherwords, how does one dynamically resize a chart in JasperReports?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to put a text band right beside the chart and estimate the appropriate height, use a scriptlet to generate enough text that would end up being close to the right height. On the text box, stretch on oversize, and the band will increase. Stretch the chart to the band height.